# Not able to capture the value of checkbox through ajax submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form through which I wish to capture the values of 3 different checkboxes.

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_save">
  <input type="checkbox" name="first"  id="first"  class="first">First <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="second" id="second" class="second">Second <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="third"  id="third"  class="third">Third <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="save-icon-btn" >
    <img src="img/Save.png" >
  </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#form_save").submit(function() 
    {
      var formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('first', first.value);
      formData.append('second', second.value);
      formData.append('third', third.value);

     jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "abc/def",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
          {
            alert(res);
            //console.log(res);
          },
        error: function(errResponse) 
          {
            console.log(errResponse);
          }
      });
      return false;
   });
```

Backend

```
$data = array(
  'first' => $this->input->post('first'),
  'second' => $this->input->post('second'),
  'third' => $this->input->post('third')
);
```

I am getting the value of first, second, third as "on" even if the checkbox is not selected. Is it possible to capture the values as on-off or true-false depending if the value is checked or unchecked

Comment: why not you directly use `$('form').serializeArray();` to capture form data and send it to php.Also for on-off value create hidden checkbox with same name with default 0 value . see here:-`<input type="checkbox" name="SomeBooleanProperty" value="true" />
<input type="hidden"   name="SomeBooleanProperty" value="false" />`

Comment: @Alive to Die i have already built the entire form which is pretty extensive, these checkboxes where addition made at a later stage, so instead of changing the entire code i am trying to find a solution around the present code

Comment: then do what i said, create hidden checkboxes for each-one.see my comment again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `radio` and `checkbox`, use `.checked`

```js
$("#form_save").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(first.checked);
  alert(second.checked);
  alert(third.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_save">
  <input type="checkbox" name="first"  id="first"  class="first">First <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="second" id="second" class="second">Second <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="third"  id="third"  class="third">Third <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="save-icon-btn" >
    <img src="img/Save.png" >
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#form_save").submit(function() 
    {
      var formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('first', $('input[name=first]').val());
      formData.append('second', $('input[name=second]').val());
      formData.append('third', $('input[name=third]').val());

     jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "abc/def",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) 
          {
            alert(res);
            //console.log(res);
          },
        error: function(errResponse) 
          {
            console.log(errResponse);
          }
      });
      return false;
   });
```